# Why does printf("%.6g, <value>) ignore zeroes after decimal point?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, printf, precision

I want to print maximum of 6 digits after the decimal point, so I used the following:

```
printf("%.6g",0.127943989);
```

the output of `printf` is 0.127944 which is correct, but when I tried this:

```
printf("%.6g",0.007943989);
```

the output became 0.00794399 which is not what I expected to see!

It seems that `printf` ignores zeros after the decimal point. So how can I force it to output maximum of 6 digit precision?

Comment: Try to add a # not sure if that works.

Comment: It seems that the number of decimal places is really the number of non-leading-zero dcimal places.

Comment: Which C library are you using? glibc does not seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the `"%f"` format specifier:

```
printf("%.6f\n",0.007943989)  // prints 0.007944
```

what you're looking for?  Keep in mind that this won't automatically switch over to the `%e` format style if the number warrants it, so this might not be exactly what you're looking for either.

For example, the following:

```
printf("%.6g\n",0.00007943989);
printf("%.6f\n",0.00007943989);
```

prints:

```
7.94399e-005
0.000079
```

and it's not clear if you want the exponential form for the smaller numbers that `"%g"` provides.

Note that the spec for `%f` and `%g` has a slightly different behavior for how the precision specification is handled.

- for `%f`: "the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification"
- for `%g`: "with the precision specifying the number of significant digits"

And that the run of zeros after the decimal point do not count toward significant digits (which exlpains the behavior you see for `%g`).

Comment: %f would print **EXACTLY** 6 digits after decimal point. I want **maximum** of 6 digits. for example if if the number is "0.12" i would like to have 0.12 but if it's "0.0012345678" i would like to have 0.001234
and I have no problem with exponential form.

Comment: Umm... thanks, but how I can produce the expected result? I can't use %f because I don't want fixed-6-digit precision. and I can't use %g because of the explanation you gave. what can I do?

Comment: Well, there's probably a better way, but since I'm not too bright when it comes to floating point stuff, I'd probably format the thing using `%f` with `snprintf()` and then strip off trailing zeros. Or something like that. But like I said, someone probably knows a better way...

Comment: @MichaelBurr Sadly AFAIK your way is the only solution for this. I'm waiting for a better way as well :(

Answer (score 1):

The ISO C standard requires that

> An optional precision, in the form of a period ('.')   followed  by 
>   an optional  decimal  digit string... This gives ... the maximum 
>   number  of significant  digits for **g** and **G** conversions

Here is the output that you would get with GNU libc (GCC 4.5.1, libc 2.11; GCC 4.6.3, libc 2.15)

```
printf("%.6g\n", 0.12);
0.12
printf("%.6g\n", 0.1234567890);
0.123457
printf("%.6g\n", 0.001234567890);
0.00123457
printf("%#.6g\n", 0.001234567890);
0.00123457
printf("%.6g\n", 0.00001234567890);
1.23457e-05
printf("%#.6g\n", 0.00001234567890);
1.23457e-05

printf("%.6f\n", 0.12);
0.120000
printf("%.6f\n", 0.1234567890);
0.123457
printf("%.6f\n", 0.001234567890);
0.001235
printf("%#.6f\n", 0.001234567890);
0.001235
printf("%.6f\n", 0.001234567890);
0.000012
printf("%#.6f\n", 0.001234567890);
0.000012
```

Comment: Yap. It's Microsoft you know! ;P *sigh*

Comment: Am I missing something?  The only difference I see between MSVC's output and GCC 4.6.1 on Linux 3.0 (I don't know which libc is used) is that MSVC uses 3 digit exponents instead of 2 digit exponents (ie., MSVC prints `1.23457e-005` while libc prints `1.23457e-05`).

Comment: @michael-burr Apparently OP is getting 0.00794399 in VC++2010 instead of 7.94399e-005. I cannot confirm it either.

Comment: @Dmitri: the OP is getting `0.00794399` when passing in the number `0.007943989` to `printf()` and using the `"%g"` specifier. That's what should be printed (and is also what libc prints).  If `0.00007943989` is passed instead then MSVC prints `7.94399e-005` compared to libc's `7.94399e-05`. MSVC follows the C90 standard, which only says that the exponent will have at least two digits (the C99 standard says that it will have at least two digits, but more only as necessary).

Comment: This answer is citing the wrong source, but otherwise correct. It's ANSI/ISO C that specifies the behavior of `%g`.